# how to append a custom directive inside an another custom directive on click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive called  composed of a button
When I click on this button, I want to append en entire row that is already defined as a custom directive by itself called

here is the HTML

```
 <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <row-creator></row-creator>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Here is the directive declaration  for the button

```
app.directive('rowCreator', function() {
return {
    restrict: "AE",
    template: "<button>Add Row</button>",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        element.bind('click', function(){
           element.append(<exception-row></exception-row>);
           console.log('appended');
        })

    }
}});
```

However, if I replace `<exception-row>` with an element that does not need angular interpretation such as `<p>this is some text</p>` it works well. Which makes me think it has something to do with compile maybe but I have been trying for hours I don't manage to do it.

Comment: working solution:      app.directive('rowCreator', function() {
return {
    restrict: "AE",
    scope: {},
    template: "<button ng-click='addRow()'>Add Row</button><exception-row ng-repeat='row in rows track by $index'></exception-row>",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
       scope.rows = [];
       scope.addRow = function() {
           scope.rows.push(scope.rows.length); // or whatever else you want
       };
    }
}});

Answer (score 0):

You will have to compile the HTML using [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object). So after appending you will have do something like:

```
$compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use templating:

```
app.directive('rowCreator', function() {
return {
    restrict: "AE",
    scope: {},
    template: "<button ng-click="addRow()">Add Row</button><exception-row ng-repeat="row in rows track by $index"></exception-row>",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
       scope.rows = [];
       scope.addRow = function() {
           $scope.rows.push($scope.rows.length); // or whatever else you want
       };
    }
}});
```

Comment: Hi @JB Nizet, That would be great if you could provide Jsfiddle demo

Comment: yes I do not manage to append the row in the desired row, it just appends it to  place I don't want to